# How to list all the removable devices with DBus and UDisks2?

Tags: d, dbus, udisks

I need to list, filter and open block devices with UDisks2. I am trying to list all the removable devices.

The [`GetBlockDevices` method](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Manager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Manager.GetBlockDevices) provided by UDisks2 requires a `a{sv}` type. If I am not mistaken, it's a HashTable of string keys and Variant values.

How can I use this information to list the devices? So far I tried the following:

```d
import std.stdio, ddbus;

void main()
{
    Connection conn = connectToBus();
    PathIface obj = new PathIface(conn, "org.freedesktop.UDsks2",
            "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/Manager", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Manager");

    writeln(obj.call!string("GetBlockDevices", "org.freedesktop.DBus", ???));
}
```

The [`call`](https://ddbus.dpldocs.info/source/ddbus.simple.d.html#L22) method requires an `Arg` at as it's last parameter. How can I provide a `a{sv}` in there?

---

I am using the [`ddbus`](https://code.dlang.org/packages/ddbus) library.

---

For args, I used `Variant!string[string]` since Variant itself is a templated type. I also removed the superfluous "org.freedesktop.DBus" from the call method parameter.

```d
import std.stdio, ddbus;
import ddbus: Variant;

void main()
{
    Connection conn = connectToBus();
    PathIface obj = new PathIface(conn, "org.freedesktop.DBus",
            "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/Manager", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Manager");

    Variant!string[string] arg;
    writeln(obj.call!string("GetBlockDevices", arg));
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

> ddbus.exception.DBusException@../../.dub/packages/ddbus-2.3.0/ddbus/source/ddbus/thin.d(833): org.freedesktop.DBus does not understand message GetBlockDevices

Comment: The `Args` there in that source can be any type... and that a{sv} thing I believe is a `Variant[string]` in D... so try declaring `Variant[string] args;` and then pass it to your ??? thing and let me know if it works.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe OP edited.

Comment: the other type thing that comes to me is the dbus docs say "out ao", i believe that means "array of objects" yet you put string in there. I think ddbus calls that `ObjectPath[]` instead. (sorry I'm not more helpful, I looked at htis lib years ago but never actually used it, so im just trying to compare your code to the docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues are:

1. The D-Bus name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 is on the system bus (not on the session bus), so the `connectToBus()` call needs to be changed.
2. The bus name is [org.freedeskop.UDisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/ref-dbus-overview.html#ref-dbus-well-known-name), not org.freedesktop.DBus
3. The return value of GetBlockDevices is `ao` (array of object paths), but you are calling it with `call!string` which means you would get back a string. Change this to `call!(ObjectPath[])`
4. (optional) you made your arguments `Variant!string[string]`. The `Variant!T` type in ddbus is a helper which will just make any type T act like a variant in the dbus protocol, but it doesn't actually allow any additional types. If you want to support passing any types ddbus supports either using `std.variant : Variant` or there is a special type you can use with the ddbus variant using `Variant!DBusAny` which is a more lightweight tagged union with only support for all the dbus types (and more introspection)

I believe this code is what you want with all the issues fixed:

```d
import std.stdio, ddbus;
import ddbus : Variant;
import ddbus.c_lib;

void main()
{
    Connection conn = connectToBus(DBusBusType.DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM);
    PathIface obj = new PathIface(conn,
        busName("org.freedesktop.UDisks2"),
        ObjectPath("/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/Manager"),
        interfaceName("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Manager"));

    Variant!DBusAny[string] arg;
    writeln(obj.call!(ObjectPath[])("GetBlockDevices", arg));
}
```

In this code I have also used the type-safe ddbus API, which makes the arguments in PathIface more clear. The type-safe API requires ddbus 3.0.0-beta.1 or above.

Example output:

```
[/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1p2, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb3, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sr0, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1p1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sde, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb2, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sde1, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb4, /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdd]
```